# How to make Hummus that doesn't have a hardened layer?

Tags: hummus

When hummus has stood outside for some time, a harder layer on top forms.

Can this be avoided?

Comment: How are you storing it?

Comment: cover with olive oil.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Plastic wrap works for storage.

Some folks brush olive oil to the top of the hummus to create a barrier from the air drying it out when it sits out on a table waiting to be eaten.

Answer (score 3):

Plastic wrap, and press it to the surface of the hummus rather than over the edges of the container.